# apply() function to columns of a matrix and elements of a numeric vector, respectively, in order

Tags: r, matrix, vector, apply

I have a function `f(list,t)` where the first argument is a `list` and the second one `t` is a number.  I wanna apply f to columns of a matrix M and elements of a vector T respectively.  Hence, if columns of M are (M_1,M_2,...,M_k) and T = (t_1,t_2,...,t_k), I want to get the following :

f(M_1,t_1), f(M_2,t_2), ..., f(M_k,t_k).

Is there an efficient way doing so without using for loop?

For example if

```
f <- function(list,x) {x %in% list}
M <- matrix(1:12,4,3)
T <- c(1,2,10)
```

I expect to get

```
TRUE FALSE TRUE
```

The following line applies f on each column of M and each element of T

```
apply(M,2,f,T)
```

But what I need is just the diagonal of this output, so I want a way to avoid extra computations.

Comment: `rowSums(t(M)==T) > 0` is another option - not very flexible to changing `f` but will be fast for large `M` and `T` objects.

Comment: @Onyambu - but OP specifically says they want to compare `M_1` with `T_1` , `M_2` with `T_2` etc. Which suggests to me any `Map` `mapply` `map2` or matrix comparison solution is appropriate.

Comment: @thelatemail I see i see.. i must have misread the question.. then even the solution i gave wont work.. thank you

Comment: I retitled *"apply() function to columns of a matrix and elements of a numeric vector, respectively"* which gets the requirement across better. You don't want full apply() on all permutations of columns and elements.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `sapply` using the number of columns in the matrix. Later, we use `any` to return True (if any) value from each column

```
Tr <- c(1,2,10)
sapply(seq(ncol(M)), function(x) any(f(M[,x], Tr)))

[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: Surely `f(M[,x], Tr)`?

Answer (score 2):

Convert your matrix to a data frame and then use the `map2` function from the `purrr` package:

```
library(tidyr)
df <- as.data.frame(M)
unlist(map2(df, t, f))
```

Also it is a terrible idea to name a variable `T` (or `F`) as that can cause a ton of problems with logical terms.

Comment: If you're going to make a point of not using `T`, don't use `t` or `df` for names either, seeing as they are both functions included in default R packages.

Comment: True (pun intended)

Answer (score 1):

```
mapply(f,as.data.frame(M),T)
```

`as.data.frame` is needed to convert `M` to the list of the matrix columns, and `mapply` applies `f` to the produced list and vector `T` in a pairwise fashion.